# Is there utils functions that merge flatMap and flatMapIterable?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm using Reactor 3 in Java and I am ofen finding myself in front of this case :

I have a Mono<A>, that I map to a Mono<List<B>> (flatMap), and then I want to transform this into a Flux :

```java
public Flux<B> processFragment(Mono<A> input) {

  //myProcessor.doIt(A a) returns a Mono<List<B>>
  return input.flatMap(myProcessor::doIt).flatMapIterable(data -> data);

}
```

The operator here seems like nonsense, and easily replaceable with a no parameter method : `.flatMapIterable(data -\> data);`

Is there some operator that get rid of this ? And no, I cannot make myProcessor returns a Flux.

Thank you

Comment: Not a solution, however an alternative is `input.flatMap(myProcessor::doIt).flatMapMany(Flux::just)`

Comment: Not sure what is your concern but if you don't like `.flatMapIterable(data -> data)` you can use `.flatMapIterable(Functions.identity())` or `.flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)`. Identity Function is very common pattern in functional programming.

Comment: The `.flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)` approach seems to be the most readable, thank you. Still not an operator but visually more acceptable than a lambda that consumes itself